# Books explaining cosmological theories and how scientists created them

Tags: cosmology, resource-recommendations, history

It is my understanding that the way cosmologists formulate theories like big bang theory, steady state universe theory, heliocentrism, etc, is by observing the sky using telescopes and imagining explanations for what they see. Are there any good books that I can read to learn more about these theories and the scientific processes that lead to them, that go into details?